# Nodejs res.status().send() returns "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: node.js, request, fetch

I have a nodejs react app where I fetch some data to the server:

```
await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DR_HOST}/validate`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: valBody,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
```

After that, the data will be validated to see if there are any errors within its content.
If everything is fine, a 200 status code is returned (manually or by default) back as response, and then something else should happen:

```
.then(res =>
{
     console.log(res)
     if (res.status === 200)
     {
    //do stuff
```

If there is an error, a 400 code will be sent

```
 if (error)
    {
        const msg = error.details.map(e => e.message).join(',') //
        res.status(400).send("Invalid Data")
        throw new ServerError("Invalid Data", 400)
    }
```

Sending only `res.status(400)` without .send will only return a 200 res. Everything works fine but an error is thrown: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. This happens only because I send a message after the status code `res.status(400).send("Invalid Data")`, but as I said, returning only a status code `res.status(400)` will not affect the response status leaving it to 200. What should I do?

Comment: Please show us your entire request handler, not just pieces of it.  The error you ask about usually occurs when you have some path through your code that will attempt to send more than one response.  The second one will cause the error you see.

Comment: It's also possible that `throw new ServerError("Invalid Data", 400)` is causing the problem.  A synchronous exception in a request handler will be caught by express and it will attempt to send an error response, but you've already done `res.status(400).send(...)`.  So, remove either the `throw new ServerError("Invalid Data", 400)` or the `res.status(400).send("Invalid Data")`.  Don't have both.  That's a guess, we need to see the WHOLE request handler to know for sure what to suggest.

Comment: @jfriend00 `throw new ServerError("Invalid Data", 400)` was causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible that

```
throw new ServerError("Invalid Data", 400)
```

is causing the problem.  A synchronous exception in a request handler will be caught by express and it will attempt to send an error response, but you've already done

```
res.status(400).send(...)
```

So, remove either the `throw new ServerError("Invalid Data", 400)` or the `res.status(400).send("Invalid Data")`.  Don't have both.  That's a guess, we need to see the WHOLE request handler to know for sure what to suggest.  And, depending upon how the code is structured, you may also need a `return` to keep any other code paths from executing.